# JQGrid, Telerik, DataTables etc. Which one is good?

Tags: jqgrid, telerik, datatables

Telerik
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

JqGrid 
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

DataTables 
http://www.datatables.net

Any other free grid which you think is better.

So which one is easy, powerful to use. ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: If you are wanting to use  DataTables in .NET, you can use my library: https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably find this interesting: [jQuery Grid Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations)

We've been developing an app for the past few months using jqGrid and it is great.

You'll see on StackOverflow there are over 1000 JqGrid tagged [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) - so this site alone is a great resource available to you when using JqGrid.

Comment: I see telrik very rich a free for ASP.NET MVC. Why not developers perfer that? Or is it only for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: The reason there are so many jqGrid questions is because the documentation is horrible. DataTables has much better documentation, and feature parity as of the time of this writing. DataTables has a forum on its site with more than 3500 questions - so the support will be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into what suite fits you best. Since all of these are offered for free I would try implementing each one in order to see what you prefer. I personally use Telerik's Extensions for ASP.NET MVC and find them very intuitive and easy to use, and they have great performance to boot. I highly recommend looking at their [online demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid), as well as their [online documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-introduction.html) and [forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc.aspx). Of course there's items around on SO regarding them as well ;)

Comment: Telerik is not free. Can I use Telerik for my client sites?

Comment: Some is free, some is not.  The basic MVC UI stuff is free and open source (takes a bit to find the source though).  They charge for support as well as their client side libraries (WPF, Silverlight, etc.).  Their Rad tools and most everything else however is not free.  The easiest way to install is with NuGet - just search for Telerik and their free MVC tools can be installed.

Comment: @pirzada - you can read the details of their license here: http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx